# How to do a 50$ donation

Tags: 12.04, donation

I have been using Ubuntu for many years and would like to give 50 CDN dollars, using my Visa card not Paypal.

How do I proceed

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After choosing either 32bit or 64bit when downloading Ubuntu you will be presented with a donation page as seen here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts

Click on the  pay with Paypal button and you will be presented with an option to pay via credit or debit  card. You can use this option without actually ever joining paypal[image: Paypal]al.

Answer (score 0):

If you go for donation and don't have a paypal account you can make one for free and it wont charge anything.. You can use your visa on many sites with paypal as its widely used trusted gateway...